# How to enable/disable any DiagnosticAnalyzer at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I'm writing some DiagnosticAnalyzer for Visual Studio 2015 (`Roslyn`), I want to implement a dialog options, which allows user to enable/disable any `DiagnosticAnalyzer` they like, how can I achieve that?

Currently, as I investigated, `DiagnosticDescriptor` has property `isEnabledByDefault`, which only affects at the time you install the extensions.

For example: I have class `DiagnosticAnalyzer` like this:

```
public class RedundantModifierAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    // class implementation
}
```

and I want to achieve something like this:

```
analyzerManager.DisableAnalyzer<RedundantModifierAnalyzer>()
```